# print jar version and set image tag

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecr

I want to create Jenkins job which builds an docker image and pushes it into aws ecr registry. I tried this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        JENKINS_CREDENTIALSID = "12223-9ef5-4d89-8e14-4972d63325c5"
                
        AWS_ACCOUNT_ID="123456789"
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
        IMAGE_REPO_NAME="testio:latest"
        IMAGE_TAG="latest"      
        REPOSITORY_URI = "${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:version-${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }
    stages {       
        stage('Build Image') {
            steps {
                sh "echo 'building..'"
                // configure credentials under http://192.168.1.7:8080/user/test/credentials/ and put credentials ID
                git credentialsId: '8f6bc3ab-9ef5-4d89-8e14-4972d63325c5', url: 'http://192.168.1.7:7990/scm/jen/spring-boot-microservice.git', branch: 'master'

                // execute Java -jar ... and build docker image
                sh 'chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew clean build --no-daemon'

                //sh 'docker build -t spring-boot-microservice .'
                sh 'docker build -t ${IMAGE_REPO_NAME} .'
            }
        }
        // Uploading Docker images into AWS ECR
        stage('Push Image into AWS ECR registry') {
            steps{                   
                 script{
                        docker.withRegistry('https://${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com', 'ecr:us-east-1:aws-credentials') {
                    sh '''
                        VERSION=$(cat build.gradle | grep "version = " | awk '{print $3}' | sed "s/\'//g")
                        REPOSITORY_URI = "${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/testio:${$VERSION}"
                        
                        docker tag ${IMAGE_REPO_NAME} ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}
                        docker push ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}    
                        
                        docker tag ${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} ${REPOSITORY_URI}
                        docker push ${REPOSITORY_URI}                           
                    '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }              
    }
}
```

But I get error:

```
Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ cat build.gradle
+ grep version = 
+ awk {print $3}
+ sed s/'//g
+ VERSION=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins_master@tmp/durable-f7124918/script.sh: 3: Bad substitution
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue? If possible can I simply the code?

Comment: Have you considered converting this to Jenkins Pipeline code? It would probably be much easier for you, and fix your issue.

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: These should get you to full conversion without Groovy: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers

Comment: ok, thanks. Back to the post. Can you advise how to fix the issue, please?

Comment: could you please share the build.gradle file?

Comment: @PeterPenzov look at the line that starts `REPOSITORY_URI = "` you have there `${$VERSION}` at the end, it is a bad syntax, change to `${VERSION}` or `$VERSION`.